# css list horizontal navigation with a border-right

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
#box {
    width:160px;
    height:50px;
    background-clip:padding-box;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    left:1.4em;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
    float:right;
    z-index:200;
}

#boxlist li {
    position:relative;
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline-block;
    bottom:1em;
    margin-left:-2.5em;
    padding-right:1.5em;
    float:left;
    border-right:rgba(255,255,255,1) thin;
}
```

```
<header>
    <div id="box">
        <ul id="boxlist">
        <li class="imgli">
                <img src="images/banner-social-icon-twitter.png" class="boximg">
            </li>
            <li class="imgli">
                <img src="images/banner-social-icon-facebook.png" class="boximg">
            </li>
            <li class="imgli">
                <img src="images/banner-social-icon-email.png" class="boximg">
            </li>
        </ul>   
    </div>
</header>
```

Hi, I have a black box with a horizontal navigation containing 3 images/links. I wanted a white right border after each *<li>* but no border is showing up.

Comment: `border-right: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,1);`

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle link?

Comment: thanks aldanux /10char

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're lacking an attribute at the `border-rigt` property explaining how the borderline should be styled such as `solid` or `dotted`, like this:

```
#boxlist li {
  border-right:thin solid rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
```

Comment: That syntax isn't right, either. The correct syntax is `border-right: [width] [style] [color]`. Reordered like this should work: `border-right: thin solid rgba(255,255,255,1);`

Comment: @EfrainReyes I thought width came last, thanks for clearing that up!